# SoapUI mock service - Transfer values between two mock services

Tags: web-services, groovy, mocking, soapui

I have two mock soap service. Through groovy script, i need to declare a global variable in one mock service and access / modify that variable in another mock service when the mock service get invoke.

Declared a global variable like this in mockservice1 --> mockresponse --> operation.

```
myData = "12345"
```

I would like to access and modify 'myData' value inside, mockservice2 --> mockresponse --> operation.

I was able to access the value between different operations which are under one service(service where the value is declared).

Am using soapui free version 5.2.1.

Comment: You may be able to send that required data in the 2nd request as part of request or header, right?

Comment: @Rao  I do not want to modify the request and response structure by including 'myData' parameter. 'myData' is just wanted to perform some validations. So want to have the value only in groovy script level between two mock services.

Comment: What happens if that is real time service? Is it something user needs to send or service has to manage itself?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using a file to store variable value.
If both mock services are in the same SoapUI project you can use relative file path (relative to project folder)

```
def path = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
def file = new File(path.projectPath+"//YourFile.txt")
```

Otherwise, you can use absolute path

Reading from and writing to a file:

```
someVariable = file.text
file.text = "Text to be written into file"
```

Comment: In case of running soapUI mock in Docker container, make sure user used by container has proper read/write permissions